# Python PyCrypto RSA Blind and Unblind

Tags: python, cryptography, pycrypto

I am trying to perform blinding and unblinding on a hash.

Following:
https://gdata-python-client.googlecode.com/hg/pydocs/gdata.Crypto.PublicKey.RSA.html#RSAobj_c-unblind

I have:

```
messageHashed = md5.new('MyMessage').digest()
print 'Message MD5:%s' % messageHashed
blindSigned = loadedPublic.blind(messageHashed,123)
print 'Blinded: %s' % blindSigned
blindSigned = loadedPrivate.sign(blindSigned,loadedPrivate.n)
print 'Blinded Signed: %s' % str(blindSigned)

unblind = loadedPrivate.unblind(blindSigned,123)
print '-------------'
print 'Unblinded: %s' % unblind
verify = loadedPrivate.verify(unblind,(loadedPrivate.n,loadedPrivate.d))
print 'Verify: %s' % verify
```

(I have previously loaded the public and private key and thats working fine)

Now, my issue is, when it runs, I get this output:

```
M<ssage MD5:?.Z?3??f2??
Blinded: ?YL⽥p??j+Z<I?vxV??{5??
??>[??? ??r?"l
??d?ڸYC????k?U?Q?????C?0?D??*T8?}?P?9~$??'?p??ZR:2? sh͓l??kXvU??d]???$?c聻?b??@?
Blinded Signed: (122872721681409041185513323026772702402844983846953530757782619983060590754290923453963299094289086410649560247540686534912830758097386690290305557644701999751846538319065094741731992734124277081554060855405114566548615303949954231396930615801829673187895538075706631646002356108979884582511973944741160960028L,)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "NewClient.py", line 103, in <module>
    unblind = loadedPrivate.unblind(blindSigned,123)
  File "build/bdist.macosx-10.8-intel/egg/Crypto/PublicKey/pubkey.py", line 165, in unblind
  File "build/bdist.macosx-10.8-intel/egg/Crypto/PublicKey/RSA.py", line 247, in _unblind
    object = RSAobj
  File "build/bdist.macosx-10.8-intel/egg/Crypto/PublicKey/_slowmath.py", line 47, in _unblind
OverflowError: cannot fit 'long' into an index-sized integer
```

Even though the unblind function is documented as follows:

```
unblind(self, M, B)
unblind(M : string|long, B : string|long) : string|long
Unblind message M using blinding factor B.
```

It does not seem to accept it.

Can anybody point me in the right direction? I have been at this for hours.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Two things stand out as I'm trying to replicate your issue:

- On my version of Crypto (2.4.1), the `_RSAobj.blind()` and `_RSAobj.unblind()` calls appear to enforce type (i.e. you're *required* to provide a `long` or `string`, `int`s don't work). A `long` constant is denoted by adding a `L` to the end of the numerical value (e.g. `9001L`).
- The `_RSAobj.sign()` function returns a tuple. The signature ends up in element 0 of the return value.

So your code really looks like this:

```
messageHashed = md5.new('MyMessage').digest()
print 'Message MD5:%s' % messageHashed
blindSigned = loadedPublic.blind(messageHashed,123L)
print 'Blinded: %s' % blindSigned
blindSigned = loadedPrivate.sign(blindSigned,loadedPrivate.n)[0]
print 'Blinded Signed: %s' % str(blindSigned)

unblind = loadedPublic.unblind(blindSigned,123L)
print '-------------'
print 'Unblinded: %s' % unblind
verify = loadedPublic.verify(unblind,(loadedPrivate.n,loadedPrivate.d))
print 'Verify: %s' % verify
```

This code runs, but probably doesn't do what you really want it to do; in particular `verify` will always end up being `False`.

What you have after unblinding is the valid RSA signature of `messageHashed` using the p, and `_RSAobj.verify(self, M, signature)` is the correct function signature (with `signature` required to be a 2-tuple, the 0th element of which is the actual RSA signature). So if you have

```
verify = loadedPublic.verify(messageHashed, (unblind,))
```

that *will* work as advertised (i.e. `verify` should end up being `True`).

Comment: Thank you soo much. This saved me hours more of pulling my hair out. It works flawlessly!

Also, do you use Bitcoin? If so, provide an address and I'll tip you for your help:) Thanks again!

Comment: @user2225961 16So8uNJ9vqaC4zM2BUP6pi5b8L1bq6TTv :)

Answer (score 0):

Looking at this off the top of my head, you'd want to extract the contained digest in the signature in order to get the unblinded data out.

I'll take a better stab at this later when I get to a machine to test code out.

Comment: With the info below, (tuple and type fixes), I would recommend applying padding to the hash prior to signing (PSS is one of the newer RSA signature schemes). Also looking at this, you'd probably want to blind such that a different key was involved in the blinding, otherwise the intended purpose for blinding (signing data such that you implicitly sign an "unknown" function's operand) is lost.

Comment: If I understand blinding correctly it's the blinding factor (`123L` in this example, though rightfully it must be random and _large_) that prevents the third party from divining the message - so all operations use the _signing authority's keys_, but the blinding factor (which is required to recover the 'plaintext') is known only to the requestor, who can then use it to unblind and get a valid signature which they can attach to the original message.

Comment: The 123L was used just for simplicity, it will be generated and alot higher. Thanks for the input!